# which layer contribute more in deep neural network

Tags: neural-networks

Which layer(first few layer or last layers) contribute more to final learned deep neural network model? I'm looking for a general answer with the reason behind.

Edit: Please answer based on likelihood not interested in answer like "it based on experimental", " All layer are important " Etc....

Answer (score 1):

Which part of a car contributes more to its ability to transport people from point A to B? Is it the tires, engine, or transmission? With any of these, the car wouldn't move very well, so it doesn't make sense to compare their relative importances. Likewise, a neural network wouldn't function with the first few layers (how would you pass in the input?) nor the last few layers (how would you output predictions?).

Comment: A car can even run without tire(on just hub) , though the ride will be rough.  So the tire here is not most important but engine & transmission are. Likewise you can easily rate each components of car. My question was which layer learn more "" IN GENERAL"" first or last. I was not asking which layers are required to build NN.